# Azure (Cloud) - Deployment .. error during downloading artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-artifacts

During my deployment, an error is thrown: [image]

Where can I see more details about this error to got an Idea, what exactly is going wrong here?
It's the cloud version of azure on `dev.azure.com`

The important parts of the sourecode for the "download artifacts" part is the following:

## azure-pipeline.yaml

```yaml
  - template: ./azure-pipelines/build-wordpress.yml
    parameters:
      replaceDomainFrom: ${{ variables.sourceRepo }}
      replaceDomainTo: ${{ variables.targetDomain }}
      buildFrom: "from$(Build.SourceBranchName)"

  - stage: deployStaging
    dependsOn: build
    condition: and(succeeded('build'), eq('${{parameters['environment']}}', 'staging' ))
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployStaging
        displayName: Deploy to `Staging`-Environment
        environment:
          name: ${{parameters['environment']}}
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            preDeploy:
              steps:
                - download: none

                - task: CmdLine@2
                  inputs:
                    script: |
                      mkdir -p ./BACKUPS/$(date +%y%m%d)
                      mysqldump $MYSQL_DB > ./BACKUPS/$(date +%y%m%d)/$(date +%H%M)_wordpress.sql
                    workingDirectory: '/var/www/html'
                    failOnStderr: true
                  env:
                    MYSQL_DB: $(MYSQL_DB)
                  displayName: 'MySQL-DB Backup vom Ziel-System erstellen'

            deploy:
              steps:
                - download: none
                - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
                  inputs:
                    buildType: 'current'
                    patterns: wordpress/**
                    artifact: 'build'
                    path: "/var/www/html/"

                # import mysql dump
                - script: mysql $(MYSQL_DB) < ./from$(Build.SourceBranchName)_wordpress.sql
                  displayName: 'import MySQL Database'
                  workingDirectory: '/var/www/html/wordpress'

                # delete old sql-file:
                - task: DeleteFiles@1
                  displayName: 'delete old MySQL Import-File'
                  inputs:
                    SourceFolder: '/var/www/html/wordpress'
                    Contents: 'from$(Build.SourceBranchName)_wordpress.sql'
```

## build-wordpress.yml (linked template from azure-pipelines.yaml)

```yaml
stages:
  - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.replaceDomainFrom, false), ne(parameters.replaceDomainTo, false)) }}:
    - stage: build
      dependsOn: mysqlDumpFromDev
      jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: 'Prepare applikation for deployment'
        steps:
          - download: none
          - script: echo -e "\n\nData from \n\t${{ parameters.replaceDomainFrom }}\n will be transformed to: \n\t ${{ parameters.replaceDomainTo }}"

          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              artifactName: 'sqldump_dev'
              patterns: ${{ parameters.buildFrom }}_wordpress.sql
              path: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/wordpress
```

And this is where those artifacts are staved (in a previous pipeline):

Comment: Based on the logs in your screenshot, the `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task is downloading artifacts with pattern `wordpress/**` into the path `/var/www/html`. Hence, the failure looks more likely to happen during `deploy` phase of `Deploy to Staging -Environment`. Can you confirm the affected step please? What do you mean by `this is where those artifacts are staved (in a previous pipeline)`, is the artifacts generated by any other pipeline? But the task is search artifacts in `current` run. Are you adding any pipeline resource? Can you share a **complete** & **minimum** YAML  to reproduce it?

Comment: Are you using MS-hosted or self-hosted agent pool for all the stages? How the artifact `build` is generated? Is it generated during `build` stage with `PublishPipelineArtifact` task? What is the content in `/var/www/html/`? If downloading artifacts into another path, will the issue still reproducible?

Comment: I use the MS-Hosted one. 
Yes, you are right, the error appear in `Deploy to Staging -Environment`. It's in `jobs > strategy > runOnce > deploy > steps > Task > DownloadPipelineArtifact@2`

The artifacts that should be downloaded at this point where generated in build-wordpress.yaml. 
Full files here: https://pastebin.com/3CMMR08t (azure-pipelines.yml)
https://pastebin.com/U3tyyEs6 (build-wordpress.yml)

Comment: Hi there, Thx for the sharing. Would you consider accepting your workaround which may help others encountering similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it seems to be a bug wit dev.azure.com and Pipelines.
As If I change the pipeline not to use `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` but `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` the download work again:

[image: changed pipeline]

[image: Download work]

So even if MS recommend, to use PipelineArtifact instead of BuildArtifacts, you might run in same error like me... if so... give BuildArtifacts a try and it will save you days of try & error.

In my case it cost me a bunch of hours to fix!!

### Downside

The downside: It's incredible slower with buildArtifacts. Is something like 28 minutes upload & 4 minutse download **VS** 7 seconds upload and 4 seconds download for pipelineArtifacts

## I hope they will fix this bug soon!